# How to zip or compress resources of your .NET application

Tags: decompilation, unpacking, compilers

I am a Windows application developer, I'd build a few .NET applications and I can see It is **very easy to crack** out resources of my Application even some simple applications like Resource Editor are able to crack my application by just deleting the Registration Dialog Box to make my application a freeware without having a proper license key.

Is there any `.EXE` compressor or any other other tool which I can use to save my application resources **as well as my scripts**, Can anyone suggest me How can I **avoid Recompilation** of my script. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to explain what a "script" is.

Comment: I mean assemblies

Answer (score 3):

The idea of truly protecting resources is impossible -- every protection you implement can and will be broken. Assume this, and do not put credentials or private data in your resources/code.

The idea behind resource encryption/compression is summarized well in [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19537/XResFile-Files-Stored-in-Resources-Part-3-Encrypte), the same ideas apply to .NET. You use some encryption method, add the encrypted file to your project, load it via your code, and run your decryption/decompression algorithm on it.

Realistically, though, it sounds like you're looking for a .NET obfuscator with compression features. I don't believe stackexchange is the place for product advertisement, so here is a good objective list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_obfuscators_for_.NET

**In regards to making cracking your application more difficult,** you should consider using asymmetric encryption [as described here](http://www.drdobbs.com/licensing-using-symmetric-and-asymmetric/184401687) and license key files. Think of creative ways to perform license checks throughout your application. Using a keyfile you're preventing the possibility of anyone ever writing a keygen for your application, and adding a large number of checks for the license will make it arduous for anyone attempting to crack the application.

Answer (score 1):

- If your goal is to prevent someone tampering with your .NET application binaries, then .NET provides a solution: [Sign ("strong-name") your assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx). This process makes use of asymmetric keys and checksums, the loader will notice any changes to the signed assemblies and refuse to load them.
- If your goal is to prevent people from decompiling (looking at) your code, you need a [code obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29) tool.

Comment: Signing it will only help against MiTM and even then only if you get the key through a seperate channel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for freeware tools to zip your resources and to keep your scripts secure, then I'll recommend you to use **`Confuser`**

This is a freeware application, even you can download its source code.

Comment: A link and a little description of the tool wouldn't hurt.